# Why can't a rational function have both, a horizontal and an oblique asymptote?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, functions, rational-functions

Why if a rational function has a horizontal asymptote, it excludes the possibility of this function to have an oblique azymptote, or viceversa?

Comment: But it is an interesting fact that a rational function cannot have one asymptote in the positive direction and a different asymptote in the negative direction.  Non-rational functions can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A rational function $f(x)=\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$, where $p,q$ are polynomials, has the line $y=mx+b$ as asymptote if and only if polynomial division of $p$ by $q$ leads to $mx+b+\frac{r(x)}{q(x)}$ with $\deg r<\deg q$.
By the lower degree condition, the $\frac{r(x)}{q(x)}$ summand tends to zero as $x\to \infty$ (as well as $x\to-\infty$).

It is the uniqueness of the result of polynomial division that guarantees the uniqueness of linear asymptotes.

(Note that vertical asymptotes, i.e., poles, i.e., roots of $q(x)$, are a different matter).

Comment: Thank you @Hagen. Also your explanation applies for demonstrating why a rational function cannot have more than one horizontal azymptote right?

Answer (score 1):

Horizontal and oblique asymptotes describe the behavior of the function "at infinity".  If there is a horizontal asymptote, then the behavior at infinity is that the function is getting ever closer to a certain constant.  If there is an oblique asymptote, then the function is getting ever closer to a line which is going to infinity.  A function can't go to a finite constant and infinity at the same time.

Also, you might have an image in your head of a graph with a horizontal and oblique asymptote.  If you do, then I'll be a Hersey bar that the graph violates the vertical line test, and therefor is not the graph of a function.

Comment: Why can it not have a horizontal asymptote to $-\infty$ but an oblique asymptote to $+\infty$?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I get what you mean now.  The asymptotes of rational functions depend on the degree of the numerator and denominator.  If the degrees are the same, then you get horizontal asymptotes both directions.  If the numerator degree is one larger than the denominator degree, you get oblique.