# Is it possible to define a monotonous and differentiable function with horizontal and oblique asymptotes?

Tags: calculus, elementary-functions

I've been wondering if it's possible to define a monotonous and differentiable function that has both a horizontal and oblique assymptotes. Intuitively, seems that should be possible but I can't find a way.

- Rational functions can have either horizontal or oblique asymptotes but not both ([as per this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1934481/why-cant-a-rational-function-have-both-a-horizontal-and-an-oblique-asymptote)).
- Using exponentials: The function $f(x)=x\exp(x)/\exp(|x|)$ has both horizontal asymptote ($y=0$) and oblique asymptote ($y=x$) but is not monotone.
- Another idea would be to "rotate" a hyperbola, so one of the asymptotes is sitting horizontally, and take one of the branches. I'm not sure if that's possible.

Comment: Your third idea is the one which works.

Comment: $$f(x)=\frac 12 (\sqrt{x^2+1}+x)$$

Comment: @Crostul, could you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f(x)= \frac 12 (\sqrt{x^2+1}+x)$$

Comment: I accept this answer as it is defined in a single equation and second order differentiable

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}e^x & x\leq 0\\ x + 1 & x\geq 0\end{cases}$$

does the trick just fine, I think.

You could also do the "rotate a hyperbola" trick as well, to get a "nicer" function that is not piecewise defined. But the quickest answer from the top of my head is the one above.